Submit list from memory has no data
I have a program that uses SUBMIT to get data from another.
But I've got problem that when I submit this program, it only returns the header of the ALV grid and a lot of | symbols with no data between (see the screenshot). I have checked this program directly and it has data ALV return. I have no idea why this problem happens.

The program uses the function module REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY to display the ALV. I have tried to change some parameters but no use.

It's impossible to discuss a program behavior without the complete code and data to reproduce (remember to create a minimal program for Stack Overflow). Note that extracting the ALV content by SUBMIT ... EXPORTING LIST TO MEMORY... and LIST_FROM_MEMORY is the worst possible solution.
